# Shared ReSharper settings with out-of-source cmake builds

Tags: resharper, settings

I am using cmake to generate my solution files and I'm doing that out-of-source. So I have a myproject folder and a myproject_build folder. When I save my ReSharper settings in team solution, it creates a dotsettings file in the myproject_build folder.

- C:\

  - myproject

    - .hg
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - myproject_build

    - myproject.sln
    - *myproject.DotSettings*

How can I make sure that saving these settings goes into the source folder and be sure that all team members have the same settings?

Comment: I think the question is not clear.

Comment: @Matthias I tried to clarify my folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would place a common *dotsettings* file into *myproject*, the file that you and your team will modify in the future. During generation of the solution into *myproject_build* you should generate a *myproject.sln.dotsettings* file as well, that need to hold a reference onto the file from *myproject*. You can include any other *dotsettings* file by going to `ReSharper | Manage Settings` and then right-click any layer (team-shared in your case) and add the particular file.

Comment: I will try to look into automating the layer system. Maybe I can make cmake generate the layer settings file that points to the original source file in the myproject folder.